# Can I have multiple deciders one after another in Spring batch?

Tags: spring-batch

I am trying to do something like this:

```
step -> my_decider
            -> my_step
            -> decider
                -> step
                -> step
```

This is part of `launch-context.xml`, and `my_*` are my additions. Is this valid flow? Any better approach?